# How to bind data in dynamic multiple controls

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I start use reactive form in my angular project to make a simple form that help me to add employee time of work in his/here day and add time of breaks form: and to: maybe add one break or two or more than 2 breaks per work day. I face problem that I can't bind data from break controls.

in .ts file

```
export class AddAppointmentFormComponent implements OnInit{
  addAppointmentForm!: FormGroup
  constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder, private _wfmService:WFMService) {}
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addAppointmentForm = this._fb.group({
      typeOfDayId :['',Validators.required],
      appointMentDate: ['', Validators.required],
      from: ['', Validators.required],
      to: ['', Validators.required],
      breaks: this._fb.array([
      ]),

    })
  }

  get breaks(){
    return this.addAppointmentForm.get('breaks') as FormArray;
  }

  addBreak(){
    this.breaks.push(this._fb.group({
      from: ['', Validators.required],
      to: ['', Validators.required],
    }))
  }

  removeBreak(i:any){
    this.breaks.removeAt(i);
  }
}
```

in .html file

```
<div mat-dialog-content [align]="'start'">
  <h4 mat-dialog-title style="text-align: center;">Add New Appointment</h4>
  {{ addAppointmentForm.value | json }}
  <form [formGroup]="addAppointmentForm">

    <div class="mb-3">

      <label for="name" class="form-label">Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" name="name" type="date" required formControlName="appointMentDate">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
      <label for="" class="form-label">Type Of Day</label>
      <select class="form-select" name="dep" class="form-control" formControlName="typeOfDayId">
        <option value="">Select Type...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let type of typesOfDay" [value]="type.id">{{type.typeName}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [value]="" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          All Day
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>From</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" formControlName="from" [readOnly]="addBreakBtn">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>To</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" formControlName="to" [readOnly]="addBreakBtn">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="addBreak()" [disabled]="addBreakBtn">add break</button>

    <div formArrayName="breaks" class="row mt-3" *ngFor="let break of breaks.controls; let i=index;">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="break">Break({{i+1}}) From</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="break">Break({{i+1}}) To</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group mt-2">
          <button type="submit" (click)="removeBreak(i)" class="btn btn-danger mt-4">Remove</button>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

  <div class="btn__actions">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
    <button style="margin-left:10px ;" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>

  </div>


</div>
```

I need output from `{{ addAppointmentForm.value | json }}`
"breaks": [ { "from": "10:00", "to": "10:30" }, { "from": "14:00", "to": "14:30" } ] }

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are biding *from* and *to* to the same formControlName : `[formControlName]="i"`.

You should have a div/ng-container with `[formControlName]="n"` and two other child div with `[formControlName]="'from'"` and `[formControlName]="'to'"`